# How can i make CSS :first-letter that isn't mark-up/HTML tag function?

Tags: html, css, frontend

Quite simply I need to make the first letter in a `<p>` be a different color but there is an image before that letter some of the time. Is there a way to make `:first-letter` apply to a non HTML tag?

CSS:

```
p:first-letter {
    color: red; // this should make the "W" red"
}
```

HTML:

```
<p><img src="will.jpg">West Philadelphia, Born And Raised</p>
```

Comment: What happens if you put the text inside a span element and change the css to `p > span:first-letter` ?

Comment: It's impossible. It's database driven content and the content is created by many users in a WYSIWYG form. Some will have mark-up, so will not.

Comment: With css, you can't do that, what Wysiwyg do you use ? Maybe you can change the behavior...

Comment: @h2ooooooo: You can't `:first-letter` an inline element, and if you try to make it display as a block or inline block, it may break the OP's layout.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not possible with CSS. You need to change the HTML as suggested or do some javascript hack:

- find first-child img elements of paragraphs
- move them to the end of the paragraph
- apply style definitions on them to appear before the text

Comment: Or wrap the first letter/word with the mentioned span tag (above) dynamically with Javascript. Thus you can leave the image untouched.

Comment: Thanks. I will be looking at other alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

**In first-letter :after:before pseudo classes** don't work so i have made one trick for you i hope this will help you :-

```
  p {
  background:url(http://www.dummyimage.com/10x10/000/fff) no-repeat 0 3px;
  text-indent:10px;
  }

p:first-letter {
    color: red; 
  }
```

demo:- http://jsbin.com/uwemuy/3/edit

Answer (score 0):

"First" means first.
Change your HTML to:

```
<p>West Philadelphia, Born And Raised<img style="float:left;" src="will.jpg" /></p>
```

Comment: as Tiny pointed it out, he uses a wysiwyg and cannot control the source

Answer (score 0):

**CSS:**

```
.red_color {
    color: red;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<img src="will.jpg"><span class='red_color'>W</span>est Philadelphia, Born And Raised
```